# How to remove adjascent duplicate values from perl array

Tags: perl

I have an array @vector_count.

situation 1: Most of the time loaded with values like:

```
my @vector_count = (124130,893187,275917,601123);
```

situation 2: Some cases, it gets the values like:

```
my @vector_count = (151625,151625,1790345,1790345,158384,158384,58837,58837,308533,308533);
```

in such case I need to make sure that it re-arrange to omit the duplicates: like

```
my @vector_count = (151625,1790345,158384,,58837,308533);
```

situation 3:  there may be a situation, like any of the actual values may repeat (not all). In that case, should not delete that value thinking of it is a duplicate:

```
my @vector_count = (151625,1790345,58837,58837,308533);
```

How to include all the 3 situations.

Comment: Do you mean: "If every element of the list is duplicated, remove one of each duplicate pair; If there is at least one non-duplicate, leave the list alone"?  I.e. `(1,1,2,2,3,3) -> (1,2,3)` but `(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6)` (3 is not duplicate) is unchanged?

Comment: situation 3 is not different than situation 2, as you have it listed.  If it's like the title says and it's literally adjacent dups that you want to delete, that's doable.  But situation 3 is currently an adjacent duplicate.

Comment: Jim, your first point is correct- (1,1,2,2,3,3) -> (1,2,3) but I checked- there wont be any situation like (1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6) ( (3 is only not duplicate). Either all will be duplicated or not. But as a corner case may come like (1,2,3,4,3,5) OR (1,2,3,3,4,5) . Need to include as well

Comment: So you want to detect if ALL of the values has a duplicate, and if so, remove those duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a very specific use case that you want to detect.  If all of the array elements is paired with a duplicate, then you want to remove the adjacent duplicate.  Otherwise, you want to leave the array alone.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @vector_count = (151625,151625,1790345,1790345,158384,158384,58837,58837,308533,308533);

# Detect universal adjacent duplicates
if (! grep {($_ % 2) == 0 && $vector_count[$_] ne $vector_count[$_ + 1]} (0..$#vector_count)) {
    @vector_count = @vector_count[grep {$_ % 2} (0..$#vector_count)];
}

print "@vector_count\n";
```

Outputs:

```
151625 1790345 158384 58837 308533
```

Comment: Yes Miller, I want to detect if ALL of the values has a duplicate, and if so, remove those duplicates.